# parse xml to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser, nsmutabledictionary

I am currently trying to parse some xml data into an `NSDictionary`. This is the first time I have tried something like this and am a little bit unsure of what I am doing,

First off I am parsing some XML that looks roughly like this -

```
<Rows>
<Row ID="76" MANF="JARD" ISMANUF="F" ISSER="F"/>
<Row ID="38" MANF ="SANBIN" ISMANUF ="F" ISSER ="T"/>
<Rows>
```

I am using the `NSXMLParser` delegates, so using a `NSLog`

```
NSLog(@"attributes: %@", attributeDict);
```

on **`parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:`** delegate method and my output looks like this.

```
}
2011-10-11 08:01:15.472 Code[526:207] attributes: {
    ISMANUF = F;
    ISSER = T;
    MANF = smart;
    ID = 74;
}
2011-10-11 08:01:15.472 Code[526:207] attributes: {
    ISMANUF = F;
    ISSER = T;
    MANF = "weather guard";
    ID = 71;
}
```

I am now looking to parse this stuff into a `NSMutableDictionary` but am not toatly sure on how to go about this... I am looking to do something like this

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"row"]) {
        myDic = [[myDic alloc] init];
        myDic.isManuf = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ISMANUF"];
        myDic.isSer = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"ISSER"];
        myDic.Manf = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"MANF"]
        myDic.id = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"ID"]
      }
}
```

My question becomes dose this look right? and then if so how do I declare this mutable dictionary in the header file? and also how to I declared .isManuf .isSer .Manf .id for this `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: could I use qualifiedName variable in the method to get it to work with NSMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between a subclass of `NSObject` and a `NSMutableDictionary`.

The way you wrote it, it seesm to be an object with some attributes. If youre XML `rows` contain always the same fields, I think this is the best way. The attributes of your object are automatically "mutable", so there is nothing to worry about from this side.

It is better to use custom objects because there is less probility of an error with misspelled keys, and the code is generally more readable.

So you still need to knwo how to declare your object:

MyDic.h:

```
@interface MyDic : NSObject {
   BOOL isManuf;
   BOOL isSer;
   NSString *manf;
   NSUInteger id;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isManuf;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isSer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *manf;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger id;

@end
```

MyDic.m

```
@implementation MyDic
@synthetize isManuf, isSer, manf, id;

-(void)dealloc {
   [manf release];
   [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

And don't forget to import the custom object in your main class and use the class name (with capital initial) when you create the object.

```
#import "MyDic.h"
....
myDic = [[MyDic alloc] init];
...
```

Comment: If i do go down this route, is it possible to cache my objects untill the data base is updated in the future with a database version etc?

Comment: okay so just working through this and its not going to work out, the NSXMLParsing delegate only fires back strings.. so not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Don't get your last point. If you use core data, the object would be a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and you have all the benefits of Key-Value-Coding for free on top of everything else. I strongly recommend you go with custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want .isManuf, .isSer etc... on the dictionary.

You can:

- create an objective-c class with .isManif, isSer properties (use @property and synthesize).  Although, I would recommend more readable names rather than abbreviated names - doesn't need to match xml.
- In the didStartElement method, alloc init your custom object and assign the properties.
- Since you get back n of them, you should create an NSMutableArray in the init of that class (and defined in header).  Add the item you just created to that mutable array.
- When your done parsing, you have a mutable array of all the objects in the xml.

Comment: do you this a NSMutableDictionary would be better in this case, as I will be dealing with a lot of data, I think I have read somewhere that NSDictionarys are abit faster with larger data sets.

Comment: Dictionaries are very fast when you want to lookup something be a key - but remember, dictionaries do not retain order.  An NSMutableArray is an order list which is what xml data often implies - sets of data in a certain order.  Since dictionaries and list just store a reference to an object, depending on your access pattern, sometimes it makes sense to store both - the array for the ordered list and another lookup table (dictionary) for fast access by a key.