# How to parse XML Attributes with XMLParser delegates

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser, nsobject

getting pretty despirate here.. how on earth do I parse xml that have attributes in them.. I am completely lost,

this is what the xml that I am trying to parse looks like..

```
<Rows>
<Row SKATERID="706" MANUFACTURER="A-DZG" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="F"/>
<Row SKATERID="318" MANUFACTURER="A.R.E." ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="T"/>
//...
</Rows>
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719246/parse-xml-to-nsmutabledictionary/7719742#7719742

Comment: In that sample, you even used the didStartElement callback with the attributeDict ...

Comment: yes I'm sorry I needed some more clarification. Parsing XML can be done alot of different ways and I find alot of examples do alot of different things that Im confusing myself.. So decided to come back and ask again for a fresh perspective. I know how to parse elements but not attributes.. this stuff really throws me.

Answer (score 6):

Using your NSXMLParser Delegate method:

Updated my code. Here is the code which parses your XML.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"])
  {
    myAttrDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict];
  }
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Rows"]
  {
    rowsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
      if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"])
      {
        [rowsArray addObject:myAttrDict];
        [myAttrDict release],myAttrDict = nil;
      }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
  NSLog(@"Rows Array: %@",rowsArray);
}
```

Comment: So I could pass [attributeDict valueForKey... into a NSMutableString? how could I store the object of the for attributes.

Comment: when you asked here, you got to answers on how to create an objective-c object, set the values from the attrDict and at it to something like a mutable array - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719246/parse-xml-to-nsmutabledictionary/7719742#7719742

Comment: yes I think the last part is where I am getting lost, How to create an array of objects that I can then use to display in the table..

Comment: how do I access the individual attributes of the element doing it like that?

Comment: @C.Johns Its easy,[rowsArray objectAtIndex:0] gives you a dictionary object which has all values. So [[rowsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"SKATERID"] and [[rowsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"] , etc... same for rest of objects in that array.

Comment: alright. I understand what yours saying (just have to try it myself now).. Also I am super greatful.. its been a long week.

Comment: any chance your interested in some contract work now and then ? I have some deadlines on the work I'm doing and am fairly new to things... :)

Comment: @C.Johns sure. Send me an email here: nikita.stackoverflow@gmail.com

Comment: thanks, I will do. I will have more time tonight to send you something with a little more detail but for now i'll just send you my details.